# How to add Datetimepicker in cakephp3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am able to display date with datepicker but unable to show datetimepicker. Can anybody please tell me what to do? Is there any libray file required?
present code is

```
$this->Form->input('time', ['format' => 'mdy', 'empty' => true, 'label'=>'Date']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code: 
More details : [date input cakephp 3](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-date-controls)

> $this->Form->date()

Answer (score 0):

you can also use datetime picker in jquery